# Sportsreference Python returning empty dictionary for date that has games scheduled

Tags: python, dictionary

I am having issues with the python API [sportsreference](https://sportsreference.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), I am trying to pull information for every nba matchup on a given date. I have been able to do this for ncaab, ncaaf, and nfl but am finding that the nba returns an empty dictionary.

Current code is as follows:

```
from sportsreference.nba import boxscore
import sportsreference

from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
box_scores_nba = sportsreference.nba.boxscore.Boxscores(now)

print(box_scores_nba.games)
```

Output is:

> {'12-26-2020': []}

Does anyone have any idea why I am not pulling any info when there are games scheduled this day? I have been trying to read the documentation for sportsreference and am getting nowhere.

Thanks -

Comment: There are games scheduled for 12/26 (the date of your post and of this comment), but I do not think any of them were final as of your posting. Try again now that Atlanta/Memphis has gone final, or tomorrow morning after all games are official?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Edited based on Comments**

The BoxScore() method only gives a value for the previous day and does not give any detail for today/upcoming days, this is because the website itself does not provide these details! [check here](https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/?month=12&day=26&year=2020).

On the other hand you can get the schedule of a particular team using this code:

```
    from sportsreference.nba.schedule import Schedule
    
    houston_schedule = Schedule('HOU')
    for game in houston_schedule:
    
        print(game.date)  # Prints the date the game was played
        print(game.result)  # Prints whether the team won or lost
```

Even then there are incorrect output I receive in the dataset!
Like the result of the upcoming games are shown as 'win'.

[image]

In  my opinion, it is better to avoid this API and go for better websites and use webscraping (unless you don't want real-time data) as I find these results very raw, confusing and misleading here and there!

Comment: There weren't any NBA games on October 1!

Comment: My bad I did not see that, I have updated based on that! Hope it helps.